# Is there an MBUnit attribute to run Row tests in the order they were defined

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mbunit, gallio, data-driven-tests

I've tried googling around for this but have found nothing.  Basically, I'd like to run each row in the order I defined it.  For example, if I have this:

```
[Row("a")]
[Row("b")]
[Row("c")]
[Test]
public void Test(string s)...
```

I want to be sure that test A is executed before test B, and test B is executed before test C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As specified in the [C# language specifications](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) (page 375):

> The order in which attributes are specified (...) is not significant. For instance, the attribute specifications [A][B], [B][A], [A, B], and [B, A] are equivalent.

Therefore, you can never rely on the order in which attributes are defined. Fortunately, [Gallio/MbUnit](http://gallio.org) provides a convenient optional parameter to most of its attributes which overcomes that limitation of the language. You need to use the optional parameter [**Order**](http://gallio.org/api/html/P_Gallio_Framework_Pattern_DecoratorPatternAttribute_Order.htm).

```
[Row("a", Order = 1)]
[Row("b", Order = 2)]
[Row("c", Order = 3)]
[Test]
public void Test(string s)
{
}
```

Please remark that `Order` works on other attributes as well. In particular it might be used on `[Test]` to specify the order in which the tests must run in the fixture.

---

Otherwise, in order to bind a single test parameter as shown in your example, you may find easier to use [`[Column]`](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=mbunit:data-driven_testing:column) instead of [`[Row]`](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=mbunit:data-driven_testing:rowBlockquoteBlockquote); and get rid of any attribute ordering constraint by replacing 3 attributes by only 1:

```
[Test]
[Column("a", "b", "c")]
public void Test(string s)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Include 'MbUnit.Framework.TestSequence(1)' and use ProcessTextFixture instead  of TextFixture.
  [ProcessTextFixture]
 public class TestSequeunce
{

    [MbUnit.Framework.TestSequence(1)]
    [TEST]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
    }

    [MbUnit.Framework.TestSequence(2)]
    [TEST]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
    }`enter code here`
}
```

Comment: It would be considered nice to surround your code snippet by some explanation.